# How to use multiple $splice on same collection with React Immutability Helpers

Tags: reactjs, immutability

All:

I am pretty new to React Immutability Helpers, when I try to use $splice like:

> **The doc of $splice** is:
>
> {$splice: array of arrays} for each item in arrays call splice() on
>   the target with the parameters provided by the item.

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');
var collection = [1, 2, {a: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}];
var newCollection = update(collection, {
    2: {
        a: {
            $splice: [
            [1, 1, 33, 44],
            [3, 2, 55, 66],
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

I thought all operations in that $splice array, should be based on original target, take my code for example:

[1, 1, 33, 44] will replace 2 with 33, 44

[3, 2, 55, 66] will replace 4, 5 with 55 66

so the final reault should be [1, 33, 44, 3, 55, 66, 6]

But the actual result is [1, 33, 44, 55, 66, 5, 6] which seems those two operation is based on previous operation result array.

So I wonder how can I apply all operations on the original target?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about React Immutability Helpers but in JS usually you would use `slice` to keep the array to its original value. `splice` does actually modify the original array so any subsequent operation will be executed with the result of the previous.